# Jupyter Notebook rpy2 Rmagics: How to set the default plot size?

Tags: python, r, plot, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I'm using the `%%R` cell magics in Jupyter notebooks. I'm aware that you can set the plot size for each cell with, e.g.:

```
%%R -w 800 -h 600
```

But I would like to set a default for the whole notebook/R session.

I've looked at [the documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/interactive.html), seen [this blog post on the R Jupyter Notebook Kernel](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/09/resizing-plots-in-the-r-kernel-for-jupyter-notebooks.html), and have seen [Plot Size - Using ggplot2 in IPython Notebook (via rmagic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414349/plot-size-using-ggplot2-in-ipython-notebook-via-rmagic) on setting the plot size by cell, but unless I've missed something obvious, there doesn't appear to be a way to set the default plot size for plots in R magics.

Is this possible? Is there a hidden setting, or must `-w` and `-h` be set for every cell individually?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I just had the same itch, found this page, and then managed to scratch it, so hopefully this is useful to someone.

The workaround is monkey-patching `rpy2` which calls R's `png` method directly without a way to set default arguments. Note that this approach is usually a *Bad Idea*, and brittle, but cannot be avoided. It would probably be worthwhile to make a feature request for `rpy2` to include a mechanism for default arguments.

So here goes the monkey-patching:

```
# these are the defaults we want to set:
default_units = 'in' # inch, to make it more easily comparable to matpplotlib
default_res = 100 # dpi, same as default in matplotlib
default_width = 10
default_height = 9
# try monkey-patching a function in rpy2, so we effectively get these
# default settings for the width, height, and units arguments of the %R magic command
import rpy2
old_setup_graphics = rpy2.ipython.rmagic.RMagics.setup_graphics

def new_setup_graphics(self, args):
    if getattr(args, 'units') is not None:
        if args.units != default_units: # a different units argument was passed, do not apply defaults
            return old_setup_graphics(self, args)
    args.units = default_units
    if getattr(args, 'res') is None:
        args.res = default_res
    if getattr(args, 'width') is None:
        args.width = default_width
    if getattr(args, 'height') is None:
        args.height = default_height        
    return old_setup_graphics(self, args)

rpy2.ipython.rmagic.RMagics.setup_graphics = new_setup_graphics
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Currently I think that the default are the R default settings, but it would make sense to use jyputer defaults (if there are any - I'd need look that up).

The following hack would work... if "R magic" was using the default plotting settings in R. Unfortunately it does not.

```
%%R
my_png <- function(...) {
    lst <- as.list(...)
    if (is.null(lst$w)) {
        lst$w <- 1000 # default width
    }
    if (is.null(lst$h)) {
        lst$h <- 700 # default height
    }
    do.call("png", lst)
}
options(device=my_png)
```

It would make sense to open an issue on the rpy2 tracker on bitbucket to request the feature.

Comment: Hi lgautier, thanks for your answer, however no luck with that code so far; I tried with `lst$w <- 100` and `lst$h <- 100` with no effect. Removing the conditional `if (is.null(lst$w/h))`s didn't work either. I wonder if the Jupyter/rpy2 default overrides the R settings.

Comment: `lst$width`/`list$height` with and without `list$units <- "px"` also not working, having seen https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html and trying those.

Comment: It does not work indeed. I had a look at the code in rmagic and it not using R default. I am amending the answer.